# Holomorphic map from quarter plane to unit disk.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $D$ be the quarter plane where $-\frac\pi4 < \arg(z) < \frac\pi4$. By Riemann mapping theorem, there exists a holomorphic bijection from the open unit disk to $ D$ where $f(0)=1$ and $f'(0)>0$. Calculate explicitly the inverse of this function.

I am thinking maybe I can use the Cayley transform, but this is half the plane not a quarter.

Answer (score 4):

**Another Hint**: Disk$\longrightarrow $ Upper half plane$\longrightarrow $ First quadrant $\longrightarrow$D

Find the maps in each step!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $z\mapsto z^2$ maps the first quadrant to the upper half plane (and in fact any quadrant to some half plane).